# Handwritten kana that looks like ヤダ, but I can't find ヤダ in a dictionary

Tags: colloquial-language, kana, writing-identification

studying Japanese for some months now I, began translating some Japanese sentences written on pictures or drawings.
Unfortunately I came across a drawing with handwritten kana that I cannot clearly identify.

[image]

It's quite simple to read the both right kana, being ふぁ, I suppose they are pronounced as [Fa] and shall be a sound of relief, like "Ah" or "Phew".

But the two left kana are quite hard to identify for me, as I'm used to computer-written signs. So I'm not even sure whether this is Katakana or Hirakana...
The first kana could either be ヤ or や (although therefore the small dot at the top would be missing). But neither Jisho.org nor Google Translator gave any useful hints what the lower left kana is supposed to be... It might be ダ so the resulting term would be ヤダ [Yada]. But is that reasonable? No Japanese dictionary knew this term. Of course it's highly probably that this is just another term to describe a sound made by the speaker. But [Yada]? I can't imagine a reasonable equivalent nor an emotion, which the sound [Yada] could transmit.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/yada

Comment: @Ringil gave you the right link. Make sure you always look at the "other forms" in Jisho, you will sometimes find the word you are looking for there.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I will remember your hint the next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is:

嫌(いや)だ 。
I hate it!
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/嫌/#je-4410](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%AB%8C/#je-4410)

It is written in katakana, probably for emphasis.

Comment: Note that the initial _i-_ in _iya_ is often contracted in informal speech / comic books.

Comment: 「ヤダ」is learned by Japanese toddlers pretty early on as they start to figure out how to say "no!" aka "don't wanna!". It's presumably a long while before they realize it's a contraction.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that it is a contraction... That made it harder to find. Thanks a lot for your help, the translation "Don't wanna." seems quite reasonable in the context. And thank you for the link to this dictionary, I didn't know it before, but I think that I'm gonna use it much now!